# Distinguish network error from opaque response in fetch with 'no-cors'

Tags: cors, fetch, general-network-error

tldr;  **How are opaque responses distinguishable from a network error when sending a fetch request with mode: 'no-cors'?**

I believe:

- opaque responses fail silently - fetch resolves
- network errors fail the fetch - fetch rejects

*Can anyone confirm?*
(Edit: [Same approach as used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42759652/1534823))

---

**Background**: From my UI I want to check if various urls are reachable (e.g. that they are not blocked by firewall). In this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442328/1534823 it says:

> no-cors mode means that if the browser has to do anything that requires permission from CORS, it will fail silently instead of throwing an error.

**Question**:

If a fetch request with 'no-cors' header:

- ... encounters a network error - will this cause the fetch promise to reject?
- ... encounters a CORS issue - it will fail silently, i.e. the fetch promise will resolve?

Documentation:

**Pro:** In chrome dev-tools I can simulate network errors by blocking domains, which seems to indicate the above 2 statements are true - but I am not sure how reliably that reflects real-life network errors.

**Contra:** These docs fail to mention that CORS exceptions also throw a TypeError for the fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#exceptions

**Contra:** In the fetch spec: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque
it says:

> In other words, an opaque filtered response and an opaque-redirect filtered response are nearly indistinguishable from a network error.

... or can I use the CORS preflight request somehow to check if a server which disallows CORS is reachable? (or just send an OPTIONS request?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many questions here.

You are correct that an opaque response does not result in rejection of the promise. However, a CORS failure results in a network error, not an opaque response. However, you cannot get a CORS failure if you use "`no-cors`" (note that this is not a header, it's an input to a `Request` object).

With "`no-cors`" you are restricted in the HTTP methods you can use, so `OPTIONS` is not an option (no joke). Browsers are also increasingly putting limits on what "`no-cors`" can reach as these responses are problematic in a world with Spectre. https://github.com/annevk/orb has more details on this. So long term using `fetch(url, { mode: "no-cors" })` will probably not get you what you want as you will increasingly see more network errors, despite the server potentially being reachable.