# Html5 fetch from Amazon AWS s3 bucket error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fetch

In my app I am trying to fetch a file from my AWS S3 bucket using the fetch API:

```
const response = await fetch(baseUrl + url);
```

I am getting the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/044_IMH7kfc.m4a?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAZB4Y4NZS&Signature=l6QNLV1iUj%2LerlUis%3D&Expires=1586648149' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Here is my CORS configuration file from my AWS bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</ExposeHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Fetch API in my app says "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource", but "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in the CORS configuration should add that header, no?

I tried all the solutions posted here to no avail:
[Allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin header using HTML5 fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878255/allow-access-control-allow-origin-header-using-html5-fetch-api)

I also found the AWS troubleshooting page, but that was not helpful either:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors-troubleshooting.html

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm having a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65963830/1380370) and no luck so far. Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: It's been a while and my memory is a bit spotty. I think I changed some settings in my AWS S3 bucket to allow requests from anywhere. Not sure if this was what solved the error (or if it is completely safe...) but it's something you can try. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem is in format, because new S3 console allow JSON format only.

Good luck I hope that was helpful.