# Removing unwanted tags from JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Hoping someone can assist, I am performing a fetch at an endpoint within my React app using the following code:

```
try {
        const response = await fetch("https://myendpoint.com/abcd/search?c=abc123");
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        console.log(jsonData);

      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
```

and getting back the error: `server.js:1 Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

In Postman when I run this through and returning JSON, I am getting back:

```
<pre>{
       "name": "abc123",
       "location": "USA",
       "notes": "qwerty"
}</pre>
```

Now I have no control of the response and I am assuming that the error relates to the `"<"` from `<pre>`.

What is the best way to remove these tags, i.e. `<pre> and </pre>` so that I can get back valid JSON?

Comment: You can't treat the endpoint as JSON annoyingly.

Comment: The best thing is to talk to whoever builds that backend service and tell them to get their response right because there should not be <pre> tags around the json response. That is not a debate or discussion, that response is just broken.

Comment: Understand what you are saying but I don't believe that this will be possible. So there is no way I can parse this somehow and then return a valid JSON response?

Comment: If you can't get the backend changed then try `console.log(jsonData.replace('<pre>', '').replace('</pre>', ''));`

Comment: https://jsbin.com/vaguzelicu/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @bassxzero - unfortunately still get the same error - `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: `response.json()` this will try and parse the response to json for you. You need to use the raw string. Try `response.body()` or `response.text()`

Comment: @tonyfat You're probably still using `await response.json()`?

Answer (score 2):

The pre tag is coming up as the request that is made for is for an html. not for a json response.You need to pass a header with Content-Type set to application/json.
This should solve your issue.

```
try {
  const response = await fetch('https://myendpoint.com/abcd/search?c=abc123', {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  });
  const jsonData = await response.json();
  console.log(jsonData);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
}
```

Comment: @evolutionxbox @Erick - Tried this, which has seemed to have solved that issue but am now getting the error: `from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Try adding the header `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878255/allow-access-control-allow-origin-header-using-html5-fetch-api

Comment: Sorry @evolutionxbox - where exactly do I add this and on another point, should I be using Axios instead of FETCH API?

Comment: @tonyfat inside the `headers` object. I don't think using Axios would simplify anything here

Comment: @evolutionxbox - I added this and it made no difference: `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*' }` Seems like this endpoint does not have CORS enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Although I wouldn't deem this the recommended answer, it is a solution if you don't control the server and the `Content-Type` header doesn't work.

```
try {
  const response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/get');
  const responseText = await response.text();
  const convertedResponseText = responseText.replace(/\<pre\>|\<\/pre\>/gm, '');
  const responseJSON = JSON.parse(convertedResponseText);
  console.log(responseJSON);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
}
```