# Fetch call works in Postman but not localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors

I'm able to use Postman to fetch this API from Fruityvice. But when I run it locally, I run into CORS issues.

I've been referencing [Attempted Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe) and [Attemped Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878255/allow-access-control-allow-origin-header-using-html5-fetch-api) to try and clear the error, but no luck.

Any pointers and where I'm going wrong? Thank you!

**Initial Fetch Call**

```js
const fetchFruitInformation = async() => {

  const response = await fetch("https://www.fruityvice.com/api/fruit/all");
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(response.statusText);
  }

  return response.json();
};
```

Which gives me a CORS error

**Error**

Access to fetch at 'https://www.fruityvice.com/api/fruit/all' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

So then I add `{mode: 'no-cors'}` and also `{mode: 'cors}`

**Updated Fetch Call**

```js
const fetchFruitInformation = async() => {

  const response = await fetch("https://www.fruityvice.com/api/fruit/all", {
    mode: 'no-cors'
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(response.statusText);
  }

  return response.json();
};
```

**Which throws an error**

apiCalls.js:7 Uncaught (in promise) Error
at fetchFruitInformation (apiCalls.js:7)

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/dealing-with-cors-in-create-react-app

Comment: Why `no-cors`? It says "if an opaque response serves your needs" - I don't think it does, because you attempt to actually read the response the server returned...

Answer (score 0):

`https://www.fruityvice.com/api/` doesn't send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header in the response of the request, thus browser will complain CORS issue while Postman won't. One solution is to proxy all your related requests to `https://www.fruityvice.com/api` in the backend.