# Javascript Fetch CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch-api

When running the following fetch request in my React project:

```
const options = { method: "GET", headers: { accept: "application/json", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" } };
      response = await fetch(
        `https://api.b365api.com/v1/bet365/upcoming?league_id=${league}&sport_id=${sport.id}&token=TOKEN`,
        options
      ).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

The request returns with the error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.b365api.com/v1/bet365/upcoming?league_id=131095496&sport_id=1&token=TOKEN. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.`

I've searched through A LOT of different pages and haven't found an answer I can use other than using a proxy of some sort like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ which has a limit and just doesn't work in production.

Comment: You need to set the header in server response. You can only do this if you access to the server.

Comment: Is your API token valid?

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878255/allow-access-control-allow-origin-header-using-html5-fetch-api) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe) helps you?

In my experience, there are somethings that can cause CORS errors:
For me, the most common issue is a backend function error... this happens a lot when I'm coding a new feature and happens an unhandled exception in my code. This throws CORS error.

Or maybe you have to config your backend server to use CORS:

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'

const app = express()
app.use( cors() ) // - here
```

Hope I had helped you, good luck